# Oracle Cursors : Invalid Identifier

Tags: oracle, dbeaver, cursors

I need to write code that increases the salary of an employee who is over 40 years old.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE  
CURSOR kurs IS SELECT  ID_PRACOWNIKA , pensja_BR, wiek FROM PRACOWNICY p , OSOBY o ;
ID_PRACOWNIKA decimal(2):=0;
pensja DECIMAL(8,2);
wiek DECIMAL(2);

BEGIN
    OPEN kurs;
LOOP

   IF wiek > 40 
   THEN
      UPDATE PRACOWNICY 
       SET pensja = PENSJA_BR * 1.02
      WHERE ID_PRACOWNIKA = ID_PRACOWNIKA;

      dbms_OUTPUT.put_line( ID_PRACOWNIKA|| '-'||pensja);
     END IF;
 ID_PRACOWNIKA := ID_PRACOWNIKA+1;
 EXIT WHEN ID_PRACOWNIKA=6;
  END LOOP;
   CLOSE kurs;
   END;
```

Unfortunately I have SQL error

```
SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 14, column 12:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "PENSJA": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 13, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Osoby table strucuture:

```
Id_osoby NUMBER CONSTRAINT osoby_pk PRIMARY KEY,
Imie VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
Nazwisko VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
Wiek NUMBER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT ch_wiek CHECK((Wiek>=0) AND (Wiek<=125)),
Stan_cywilny VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
Telefon VARCHAR2(20),
Pesel CHAR(11) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT osoba_uni UNIQUE,
Id_adresu NUMBER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT os_ad_fk FOREIGN KEY (Id_adresu) REFERENCES Adresy(Id_adresu)
```

Pracownicy table structure:

```
Id_pracownika NUMBER CONSTRAINT pracownik_pk PRIMARY KEY,
Id_osoby NUMBER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pr_unique UNIQUE,
Id_stanowiska NUMBER NOT NULL,
Staz NUMBER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT ch_staz CHECK((Staz>=0) AND (Staz<=45)),
Pensja_br NUMBER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pen_staz CHECK(Pensja_br>=1226),
CONSTRAINT pr_os_fk FOREIGN KEY (Id_osoby) REFERENCES Osoby(Id_osoby),
CONSTRAINT pr_st_fk FOREIGN KEY (Id_stanowiska) REFERENCES Stanowiska(Id_stanowiska)
```

Comment: Can you please share what is your code doing? and what is expected from this code?

Comment: My code changes the Pensja_br column where column Wiek > 40, then it displays the id_pracownika  and the pensja that was increased.            
dbms_OUTPUT.put_line( ID_PRACOWNIKA|| '-'||pensja);

Comment: Can you also share the table structure of both the tables used in your code? There must be some easier way than what you are doing. You have used cross join in the cursor query. That is also not an obvious thing in DB.

Comment: Of course, i've just added it to main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the single update statement but as you want to print the details also. You can go with `FOR` loop as follows:

```
BEGIN 
FOR I IN (
    SELECT P.ID_PRACOWNIKA,
           P.PENSJA_BR * 1.02 AS PENSJA_BR
      FROM PRACOWNICY   P
      JOIN OSOBY        O
    ON P.ID_OSOBY = O.ID_OSOBY
     WHERE O.WIEK > 40
) LOOP
        UPDATE PRACOWNICY P
           SET P.PENSJA_BR = I.PENSJA_BR
         WHERE P.ID_PRACOWNIKA = I.ID_PRACOWNIKA;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I.ID_PRACOWNIKA || '-' || I.PENSJA_BR);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If you just want to update the data with a single query then you can use the following update SQL:

```
UPDATE PRACOWNICY P
   SET P.PENSJA_BR = P.PENSJA_BR * 1.02
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM OSOBY O
     WHERE P.ID_OSOBY = O.ID_OSOBY
       AND O.WIEK > 40
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's UPDATE clause causing the issue (and the error description say the error is on line 14 of your script)

```
SET pensja = PENSJA_BR * 1.02
```

As I see in the beginning, there is a column named pensja_BR in the table PRACOWNICY but you are trying to update the "pensija" column. Which presumably does not exist in the table.

Another things to mention here is there is a cartesian join in your cursor because you're joining two tables without any join/where conditions

UPD: the loop will probably not work here as well because you did not fetched data from. Opening a cursor will not fetch data automatically. You have to either fetch it explicitly every time in the loop

```
open kurs;
loop
  fetch kurs into some_variable
  ...
end loop;
```

or to use another for..loop statement in order to loop through the cursor

```
for k in kurs loop
...
end loop;
```

So, you need to update cursor definition with following where clause

```
WHERE p.id_osoby = o.id_osoby and wiek > 40
```

Then remove the IF > 40 statement, you don't need it anymore.
Declare a rowtype variable in DECLARE:
kurs_l kurs%rowtype;

in PLSQL:
open kurs;
loop
fetch kurs into kurs_l;
exit when kurs%notfound;

```
  ... do your stuff ...
end loop;
close kurs;
```

Comment: okay, thanks, error's fixed. But now how I can assing PENSJA_BR * 1.02 to a variable, e.g pensja?

Comment: Oh, how i can do this? Open cursor every time?

Comment: @Tacoo, just a moment. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what the expected result would be but I hava question. If you already have the columns ID_PRACOWNIKA , pensja_BR, wiek retrieved from a table why do you create some variables with the same name?

Now, what I understood from your problem is that you try to change the PENSJA_BR Column to have the value of PENSJA_BR * 1.02 for each row which has the value >40 in the column WIEK.

I think that the following code might help you with your Problem. I have tested it within my testing environment and it updates the column PENSJA_BR accordingly. Nevertheless, you will have to update it to your needs and add what you need extra.

```
DECLARE

check_stauts NUMBER;

    CURSOR kurs IS 
    SELECT id_pracownika, pensja_br, wiek
    FROM pracownicy;

BEGIN
    FOR i IN kurs LOOP
        if i.wiek > 40 THEN
        UPDATE pracownicy
        SET
            pensja_br = i.pensja_br * 1.02
        WHERE
            id_pracownika = i.id_pracownika; 
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

PS: when trying to assign a value to a variable use:

```
pensja := PESNJA_BR * 1.02
```